# WKT header spatial reference errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, well-known-text

Trying to open a created point cloud but it was rejected for its spatial reference in its header properties. Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue? Do we need to rewrite the WKT in the LAS File? If so, how do we go about that.

[image]

Comment: It would help if used the [Edit] button to place the invalid string in the Question body.

Comment: which software are you using to open the data

Comment: We are using ArcMap

Comment: We may have repaired it in LP360, but we lost the Extended Variable Length Record, which stores information that is not typically held in the rest of the LAS file’s WellKnownText, VariableLengthRecord, or PointDataRecord. Looking for another fix where this possibly would not occur.